# How to build Spring Cloud Stream JMS ActiveMQ

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I recently discovered that Spring has an alpha version of a spring cloud stream provider that leverages jms (ActiveMQ virtual destinations under the hood).  This is absolutely fascinating and I want to test it out.  I am having difficulty finding a snapshot of the dependencies I can use or being able to pull and build the correct github projects so I have the dependencies in my local repository.  I would appreciate any assistance on this.

http://activemq.apache.org/amqp.html

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-jms

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-jms/tree/master/spring-cloud-stream-binder-jms-activemq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are in the process of restructuring the repositories for the JMS binder and we don't have the CI processes that build the necessary artifacts yet (should be there in by early next week).

For now, you can try building and installing https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-jms (which also contains the ActiveMQ support). We'll decide later if we need a separate repository for ActiveMQ.

Comment: I tried building this repository, however, I do not have a snapshot version available of the parent repository showing up. (spring-cloud-build:1.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT).  Do I need to build something specific or add a repository for this?

Comment: `https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot` is a virtual repo that includes snapshots and milestones.

Comment: @MatthewFontana - try using `./mvnw clean install` (using the Maven wrapper that is part of the project) - that also includes the Spring profile with  the snapshot repositories.

Comment: Is a release for the following project planned or has this been abandoned?
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-jms

Comment: As @wyck said, does  github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-jms have been abandoned? I already have ActiveMQ and don't want to introduce more moving parts :S

Comment: @MariusBogoevici - Just checking if this project is abandoned? I am looking for a solution where events are currently published to spring-cloud-stream-kafka, but need to update kafka with activemq.  Just looking if I can make this change by updating spring-stream-brokers configuration only.